# How to get the configurations dict from a pre-configured logging object

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a `logging` object that was initialised using `logging.config.dictConfig(logging_conf_dict)`:

```
import logging.config
logging_conf_dict = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # root logger
        '': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(logging_conf_dict)
```

For testing purposes I am trying to do the operation in reverse. I want to get the configurations dict from a configured `logging` object...

something like:

```
logging_conf_dict = logging.config.dump()
```

or

```
logging_conf_dict = get_configurationns(logging)
```

Is there a way to access the configurations dict of the `logging` object as a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the original dict configuration is not persisted during the load of the configuration within the `logging` module.

So your best bet might be creating your own custom parser which will retrieve available loggers and parse their handlers and formatters.

Something like this:

```py
import logging

def parse_logging_dictconfig():
    dict_config = {"loggers": {}}

    level_name_map = {
        logging.DEBUG: "DEBUG",
        logging.INFO: "INFO",
        # etc...
    }

    loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
    for logger in loggers:
        logger_config = {}
        logger_config["level"] = level_name_map.get(logger.level)
        logger_config["handlers"] = []

        for handler in logger.handlers:
            logger_config["handlers"].append(handler.name)

        dict_config["loggers"][logger.name] = logger_config

    return dict_config
```

The example is not complete, but based on that you can get the basic idea.

Comment: I managed to get the handlers only partly. I did not manage to get the formatters :-/
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Those as well have to be stored in either the logger or handler instances, you should find them, just browse through the properties.

Comment: the names of the formatters get lost on the way, only the reference to the object remains. so to generate the "formatters" dict, I will need to create a pseudoname for each formatter object, then make sure to reference that name in the handler object.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll try to take a look at it tomorrow, as they say two heads are better than one!

Comment: Checking the constructor of the `logging.Formatter` class it seems like there is no metadata persisted about the formatter's name :(

Comment: Yes. That’s what I concluded as well last night. My solution was to give the extracted formatters a pseudonym that I also use in related handlers. Thanks for looking again. Your initial answer got me 4/5 of the way.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that information is not stored. As you can see in the source code, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/logging/config.py, `logging.config.dictConfig` only stores the passed in config in a termporary dict which gets thrown away at the end of the function (starting line 805):

```
dictConfigClass = DictConfigurator

def dictConfig(config):
    """Configure logging using a dictionary."""
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
```

and looking at the `configure` method, the dict is not stored there either.
I'm guessing the reason they do this is that `dictConfig` is acting on global variables (the default logger).